# Match breadcrumb with list item and grab it's name attribute and place into it's own href

Tags: jquery, breadcrumbs

I have a set of breadcrumbs, each with text that matches a list item of the same name

[Here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/eloiterman/r6yFG/21/)

So far I succeeded in: 
1) getting the text of the clicked link,
2) matching it to a corresponding list item
3) Initially getting that list item's name attribute
What I am having trouble with is passing that name attribute BACK to the clicked breadcrumb link and appending it to it's href (for targeting purposes)

Why am I doing this?
-because each list item will scroll and there are going to be several results,

The use case is to have the user click a row -have the breadcrumbs appear, (this is not shown in this simplified example)-so if the user scrolls away, they can click a breadcrumb and the contents will scroll back into to that row.

HTML

```
<div class="wayfinder"><a href="#">red</a>><a href="#">blue</a>><a href="#">green</a>

</div>
<ul> <a name="1"><li>red</li> </a>
 <a name="2"><li>blue</li> </a>
 <a name="3"><li>green</li> </a>

</ul>
```

Script:

```
//listen on wayfinder specific link

// -I- get text from link clicked:
$('.wayfinder a').click(function () {
    var wayget= $(this).text();
 $(this).addClass('marker');
    alert(wayget);
    var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
  //pass the attribute to back to the wayfinder  -This part isn't working-
$(this).attr("href", _href + 'listatrr');

    // search list items for matching text mark it red to identify it

$('a li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == wayget) {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
       $('li').not(this).css('color', 'black');
      //get it's attribute:

       var listatrr= $(this).parent().attr("name");
      alert(listatrr);
      //this produces an error
      //$('.wayfinder a.marker').attr("href", + listatrr);
  } 


});


});
```

[Here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/eloiterman/r6yFG/21/)

Comment: update:  http://jsfiddle.net/eloiterman/r6yFG/28/

Comment: this MAY have fixed it. BUT if there is a cleaner smarter more efficient way of doing this please check up and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below is where I corrected it:

```
var listatrr = $(this).parent().attr("name");

//alert(listatrr);
$('.marker').attr("href", _href + listatrr);
```

This will reset the event:

```
$('.wayfinder a').mouseup(function () {
    $('.marker').attr("href", '#');
});
```

**update**

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eloiterman/r6yFG/28)